# Can't install AEM and Sling plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aem

I am trying to install AEM plugin for Eclipse Indigo for Mac.
But it is giving me some network and security exceptions.

I am following this link
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dev-tools/aem-eclipse.html

[image: screenshot for exception in eclipse]

Comment: I was using Indigo. This plugin works on Luna/Kepler only.

Answer (score 1):

Check your proxy setting, or maybe a firewall problem...
Anyway, you can try to install it with the archive : 
[archive link](http://eclipse.adobe.com/aem/dev-tools/com.adobe.granite.ide.p2update-1.0.4.zip)

Installation instruction from [adobe devtools](https://eclipse.adobe.com/aem/dev-tools/):

> download an archive for instance for offline installation and pass it
>   via 'Archive' in the 'Help > Install new Software...' Eclipse menu.